# What does it mean for a graph to have O(|V|) edges?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics, data-structure

I'm doing a problem that begins with "Show that if G has O(|V|) edges...". Without tackling the substance of the problem, I'd like a formal definition of what exactly it means for G = (V, E) to have O(|V|) edges.

Intuitively, I *think* it means that given V, a graph G = (V, E) has O(|V|) edges if there is an algorithm that constructs the edges E that runs in O(|V|) time.

Is this intuition correct? Is there a more formal way to put it?

Comment: The result is an asymptotic result, right? Not a statement about any particular graph? If so, it probably means, if you consider a sequence of graphs $G$ with … and also that *the edge-vertex ratios $|E|/|V|$ are bounded as $|V|\to\infty$ (as $G$ varies)*, then asymptotically is is true that …

Comment: Correct, asymptotic result @FShrike

Comment: It means that there are constant $C$ and $M$ such that, for all $(V,E)$ such that $\lvert V\rvert\ge M$, $\lvert E\rvert\le C\lvert V\rvert$. In other words, it says that the function $g(n)=\sup\{\lvert E\rvert\,:\, \exists G=(V,E), \lvert V\rvert=n\}$ is in $O(n)$.

Comment: It means, instead of just saying that $G$ is a graph, that $G$ comes from a subset of graphs where $e = O(v)$, rather than the usual $O(v^2)$.  Which exact subset doesn't matter, any subset with this property is fine.